# How does GCC run its other programs?

Tags: gcc, exec

Maybe the title does not word the question so precisely: I know that when I run `gcc foo.c` GCC calls other sub-programs that do all the work for it, making the main gcc program just an interface. But how exactly is this done?

Does it use `system` or `exec` or some other function? The reason I want to know this because I want to build a web crawler based on a similar system, where there would be a interface program and several other sub-programs like `crawl` and `download`.

I'm sorry if this question has already been asked but I didn't find it using search or the "Questions with similar titles".

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While your question is really more general (and only using `gcc` as an example), my first idea would be to use `strace` to figure out what it's doing. On my system (Ubuntu 11.10/x64), I just ran `strace`, like so:

```
strace -F -o sout gcc -Wall -o test test.c
```

This shows system calls for the `gcc` process, while following forks (`-F`) and sending the output of the trace to `sout`. Doing this, I can see that `gcc` here calls `vfork()`, and then `execve()` in the child, though the actual program's source might just do a simple `fork()`/`exec()`.

The relevant output from `sout` is:

```
26264 stat("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=11248824, ...}) = 0
26264 access("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1", X_OK) = 0
26264 vfork()                           = 26265
26264 wait4(26265,  <unfinished ...>
26265 execve("/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6.1/cc1", ["/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4."..., "-quiet", "-imultilib", ".", "-imultiarch", "x86_64-linux-gnu", "test.c", "-quiet", "-dumpbase", "test.c", "-mtune=generic", "-march=x86-64", "-auxbase", "test", "-Wall", "-fstack-protector", ...], [/* 46 vars */]) = 0
```

At the begnning of each line is the pid of the process running. So the primary process calls `stat()` to find `cc1`, then forks, and the child executes it.

That being said, I could have answered your question without the citation; fork/exec is a common way to call sub-processes from your program.

Comment: I didn't even think of strace, I'm not a Linux person. Yeah the question really is kind of general. Thank you!