# GCC Static Linking And Separate Loader

Tags: gcc, static, linker, libc

I'm trying to understand the process of static linking, loading of GCC:

I have the following toy program

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main() {

  fprintf(stdout, "Hello World \n");

  return 0 ;
}
```

I can compile it and run file as follows:

```
       gcc -static -std=gnu99  -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c -o test;
```

But as soon as I try to separate out the compile and linking process as follows:

```
       gcc -static -std=gnu99  -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c -c;

       ld -o  test -T link.lds test.o
```

where the link.lds is

```
SECTIONS

{
   . = 0x10000;
   .text : { *(.text) }
   . = 0x8000000;
   .data : { *(.data) }
   .bss : { *(.bss) }
}
```

I get the error "undefined reference to stdouttest.o: In function `main':

```
test.c:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `stdout'
test.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `fwrite'
```

If I try adding the flag -lc to ld, it tells me that it is not found. I've tried running gcc with -lc
and/or -static-libgcc but I have the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I has no problem to run `gcc -static -std=gnu99  -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c -c && gcc test.o -o test` with gcc-4.4.7

Comment: This will work fine. But i'm specifically looking at using it with the loader (ld)

Comment: then you'd link with `-lc`, adding other staffs, like crt1.o, crtn.o, crtbegin.o, crtend.o etc., which companions with your gcc. you may run `gcc -v test.o` to check how `gcc` do the job.

Comment: I've managed to get as far as this:

gcc -static test.c  -lc -static-libgcc -c ; ld test.o  -o test -lc  --entry main --section-start=.txt=0x30000 --section-start=.bss=0x400000 --section-start=.data=0x500000 

But now I get ./test : binary not found. It says that the file is dynamically linked when I specify it as static

With respect to replicating the ld output, it relies on an object file in /tmp/...o which when I rerun the ld command, doesn't exist

This is why i'm not reusing the output of -v

Comment: Avoid using `test` as an executable name, since it is a shell builtin. Add `-v` to your `gcc`  commands to understand what is happenning, e.g. compile with  `gcc -v -static -std=gnu99  -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c -o mytest`

Comment: @raison, what's the point of `crtbeginT.o` and `crtend.o`? In this case they are not necessary. However, `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, and `crtn.o` are necessary. Where is it described what each of these are?

Comment: http://dev.gentoo.org/~vapier/crt.txt

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Global_Constructors

Comment: @Zboson with gcc-4.4.7, centos 6.5, they're required. without crtbegin.o and crtend.o, the `ld` will report requirement failure.

Comment: @raison, they are not necessary in this case with gcc-4.8.2 Linux Mint 17. But I'm more curious to know what they are for?

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
gcc -v -static -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c
```

and look for the `collect2` tag.

In my case it is

> collect2 --sysroot=/ --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -static -z relro -o test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbeginT.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. /tmp/ccoR98Xr.o --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

You have to replace the temporary object file.  In my case I replaced `/tmp/ccoR98Xr.o` with `test.o`.  Then do

```
gcc -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c
```

> ld --sysroot=/ --build-id -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -static -z relro -o test /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtbeginT.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../.. test.o --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o

- It links to the object files : `crt1.o`, `crti.o`, `crtbeginT.o`, `crtend.o`, and `crtn.o`.
- It links to the libraires: `libgcc.a`, `libgcc_eh.a`, and `libc.a`.
- You can replace `--start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group` with `-lgcc -lc -lgcc_eh -lc` if you like.

Knowing this we can simply this to

```
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=crt1.o`
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=crti.o`
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=crtn.o`
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=libgcc_eh.a`
ln -s `gcc -print-file-name=libc.a`

gcc -c -std=gnu99 -Wall -Wno-unused -g test.c
ld -m elf_x86_64 -o test crt1.o crti.o test.o libc.a libgcc_eh.a libc.a crtn.o
```

I did not use `crtbeginT.o`, `crtend.o`, and `libgcc.a` because it worked without them.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8837696/how-does-gcc-run-its-other-programs), strace does the job (show you the secrets) but you will soon realize there are tons of options in it... You need to link a few stuff together (from GNU C lib) to get your executable, not only your object... You can add grep 'exec' in the end to make it cleaner.

Uhhh, also you need to do this:

```
as obj.s -o obj.o
```

Use GNU assembler to convert your .s to .o  then link with ld.